# Using Sessions in WCF Services called from Silverlight

Tags: silverlight, session, wcf, wcf-binding

(Using Visual Studio 2008, and Silverlight 3)
-I've really looked around for this one, and now I'm just confused by all the solutions that simply won't work for me.

I'm trying to call a WCF service from a Silverlight client, which is no problem, but I can't get the service to handle sessions (I want to remember a few things about the callee between calls)

I've gathered that basicHttpBinding is no good for sessions, and I haven't managed to make wsHttpBinding work... what's the matter? I would have thought this was a pretty basic thing people would want in their WCF services, or am I just completely muddle-headed not to see how it can be done?

Comment: Hi, I don't have a solution for your question I'm afraid, but I came across this article that at least explains why it's not working with basicHttpBinding:

http://sankarsan.wordpress.com/2008/09/07/wcf-sessions/

wsHttpBinding is not supported by Silverlight unfortunately. But maybe there's some kind of workaround that will get WCF sessions + Silverlight working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

okay, seems like "Silverlight-enabled WCF Services" (WCF service with

```
[AspNetCompatibilityRequirements(RequirementsMode = AspNetCompatibilityRequirementsMode.Allowed)]
```

and basicHttpBinding instead of wsHttpBinding) can do sessions with Silverlight:
http://www.dotnetspider.com/Silverlight-Tutorial-317.aspx

Cheers, Alex

Comment: Thank you for answering, but I've already tried that example, downloaded the project and tried it again - won't work for me. (The "Silverlight-enabled WCF service" template also seems to bring on cross-domain posting errors for me.) 

I will try installing VS 2010 and then see if it works better.

Comment: HA! It works fine with VS 2010.. it seems so far.. :)
Now I just have to figure out how to give you credit for it, since your answer worked :)